# Why is the flat cotorsion pair actually a cotorsion pair?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology

I asked this question some while ago on Stack Exchange but didn't get an answer ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812523/why-is-the-flat-cotorsion-pair-actually-a-cotorsion-pair)), so I am trying it here as well.

Fix a ringed space $(X,\mathcal{O})$ and denote by $\mathcal{F}$ the class of flat modules. A module $C$ is called *cotorsion* if $Ext^1(F,C)=0$ for all flat modules $F$.

I want to see that a module $F$ is flat if and only if $Ext^1(F,C)$ for all cotorsion modules $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The category of sheaves on a ringed space is a Grothendieck category. Let $Q$ denote an injective cogenerator. We write $hom$ for internal and $Hom$ for external hom.

Let $F^+:=hom(F,Q)$. Then for any sheaf $F$ the sheaf $F^+$ is pure injective. This follows just from the adjunction $\otimes \dashv \hom$ and the fact that $Q$ is injective.

Recall that a short exact sequence $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0$ is called *pure* if it stays exact after taking the tensor product with any element. We also just say that $A\rightarrow B$ is a pure injection. A sheaf is called *pure injective* if it is injective for the family of pure injections.

Next we have to see that $F^+$ is cotorsion for any $F$.

**Lemma** Pure injective modules are cotorsion 
**Proof** Let $M$ be a pure injective sheaf, $F$ a flat sheaf and $0\rightarrow M\rightarrow E\rightarrow F\rightarrow 0$ be an extension. Apply $Hom(-,M)$ to find a splitting $E\rightarrow M$. Hence the extension is trivial and we see that $Ext^1(F,M)=0$

Now we can finally show the final result

**Proposition** $(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}^\perp)$ is a cotorsion pair 
**Proof** Let $F\in {}^\perp(\mathcal{F}^\perp)$ and $M$ be any sheaf. It is $Ext^1(F,M^+)=0$ by assumption. But we also have $Ext^1(F,hom(M,Q))=Hom(Tor_1(F,M),Q)=0$. This uses that $Q$ is injective. Since $Q$ is also a cogenerator we can conclude $Tor_1(F,M)=0$, hence $F$ is flat as desired.

Answer (score 3):

The proof is given on page 3 of Mark Hovey's paper "Cotorsion Pairs and Model Categories" http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~bshipley/hovey.pdf

After writing "It is not at all obvious that this is a cotorsion pair", he gives the proof, using pure short exact sequences. It suffices to show that if $Ext^1(D,E) = 0$ for all cotorsion $E$ then $D$ is flat. This means $Ext^1(D,M^+)=0$ for all $M$, where $M^+ = Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(M,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$. To finish the proof, Hovey shows that $Tor^1(D,M)^+ = 0$ for all $M$ (which implies $D$ is flat), using that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is injective as an abelian group (and using derived Hom-Tensor adjointness). For full details, see Hovey's paper linked above. Note: the setting here is the category of $R$-modules for some ring $R$. But, you can generalize the proof to ringed spaces (indeed, this is discussed a bit in the last section of the same paper).

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? I know the case of $R$-modules but I am unable to generalize the proof to the case of ringed spaces. One problem is that for sheaves the distinction between internal and external $Hom$ and $Ext$ has to be made.